# Why in an action parameter do I sometimes need to pass a lambda and other times not?

Tags: c#

Consider the following:

```
public void Step(Action code){}
```

To reuse this I typically pass a lambda expression through like this:

```
tr.Step(() => StaticType.SomeMethod(someParameter);
```

While at other times I can simply pass a void function without using a lambda expression :

```
tr.Step(SomeNonStaticType.SomeMethod);
```

Where SomeMethod is :

```
public override void SomeMethod(){}
```

Can someone please explain this to me?

EDIT: To be clear both have void return types. EDIT 2: If I'm asking these questions what book should I be reading (in the comments please).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841990/are-there-any-benefits-to-using-a-c-sharp-method-group-if-available

Comment: `Action` is a delegate; both class methods and lambda expressions can be used as delegates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Action` is a delegate for a method with 0 parameters and no return value.

You can pass any method that meets these criteria to your `tr.Step`.

You cannot use a method that *has* parameters or that has a return type as an `Action`, because the signatures don't match. For that you need to do something like what you're doing there with `() => StaticType.SomeMethod(someParameter)`.

Comment: Ok so it's the parameters that in this case, since both are voids.