# C# - struggling with IDE0200/csharp_style_prefer_method_group_conversion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serilog

So came back to C# after several years. A lot has changed, still trying to recollect what I knew.

Using Visual Studio Pro Version 17.5.3. Created a new project and added Serilog for logging, but it wasn't working properly, so I am looking at their debug doc - https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics. The first code line

```cs
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
```

Looks easy, passing a lambda to `Enable`. And this works as is if I open the project in vscode, when I `dotnet build` / `dotnet run`. Probably due to lack of auto-format configurations in vscode for now.

But Visual Studio seems to be formatting this line and is breaking the `build`.

I have a "default" `.editorconfig` generated at the solution level, and there's a rule in it - `csharp_style_prefer_method_group_conversion = true:silent`. This seems to be refactoring the lambda to become as

```cs
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Debug.WriteLine);
```

(notice it's removing the args, and then the `build` fails because

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1618  Cannot create delegate with 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string?)' because it or a method it overrides has a Conditional attribute   Library C:\Users\user\Work\C#\Library\Logger\Logger.cs  13  Active
```

[image]

I silenced the rule in `.editorconfig` for now - changed it to `false:silent`, but looking/hoping to understand how to solve it.

[Are there any benefits to using a C# method group if available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841990/are-there-any-benefits-to-using-a-c-sharp-method-group-if-available)

csharp_style_prefer_method_group_conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will change it to `Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.WriteLine);` it will work. Problem here is that `Debug.WriteLine` will not be emitted by compiler in non-debug build (see the [`[Conditional("DEBUG")]`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Diagnostics/Debug.cs,de18340cbf015ef1) attribute), so while the first version will become no-op (i.e. something like `() => {}`, compare [release](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0ARAlgQwOYDsB7AZwBdMBjYgblhAGZkxEBhRAb1kW+UZABZEAWQAUKMAB5CAIwBWAUwqkAfImwBKDlx47t3AL57ERhskFCIIzQF5VozIluJ086QFdcqAOoAnTKXkAGUx8eRFMdXVaGH0gA===) and [debug](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBECWAhgOYB2A9gM4Au+AxpQNzJQDMmM6AwugN7LpBmdlAAs6ALIAKLDAA85AEYArAKZ1qAPnSEAlHwFCjhwQF8T6C20ziJcKfoC826fnTP0uVYoCuxbADqAE741KoAMvikqlL4urrMSKZAA==) output @sharplab.io) for the second one compiler will not be able to emit something.

Read more:

- [Conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation)
- [`ConditionalAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=net-7.0)